# Angular Interceptor: headers added in the request not set properly, can't fetch them from the API

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to add some custom headers in my angular interceptor as follow:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpJwtAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    localStorage.setItem('token', 'qsdfqsdfqsdfqsdf');
    if (localStorage.getItem('cuid') && localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'sm_universalid':'blablabla',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
        },
      });
    }



    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

The above interceptor was added into providers property in **app.module.ts**:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpJwtAuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    { provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: environment.apiUrl },
  ],
```

In my spring boot application, I am adding a filter to check if the headers are received, if not it throw an exception:

```
String cuid = request.getHeader(SM_UNIVERSAL_ID);
if (cuid == null || cuid.isEmpty()) {
    log.error("Failed authentication: cuid header not found in the request or it is empty");
    throw new FailedAuthenticationException("cuid header not found in the request or it is empty:"+cuid);
}
```

Unfortunately the filter can't find the added headers, I tried to log the list of headers received and I found that they were added as value for **access-control-request-headers**  header:
[image]

How can I get those headers separately? and why they were added into **access-control-request-headers** header?

Bellow a snapshot of my spring security class config (the header filter is applied there):

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final HeaderVerificationFilter headerVerificationFilter;
    private final JwtAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter;
    private final JwtAuthEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //csrf is disabled because we are not using cookies
        http.csrf().disable();

        // No session will be created or used by spring security
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        //Entry points
        http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/login").permitAll()
                //Disallow everything else
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        //if a user try to access a resource without having enough permissions
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint);

        // Apply Header and JWT filters
        http.apply(new JwtTokenFilterConfigurer(headerVerificationFilter, jwtAuthorizationFilter, jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint));
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Allow swagger to be accessed without authentication
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs")//
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**")//
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")//
                .antMatchers("/configuration/**")//
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**")//
                .antMatchers("/public");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero no it is not, it is just an constant holding the same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but I had to add my own custom CORS Policy config in my spring security config class, like that:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // allow requests
    config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));

    //allowed methods
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "OPTIONS", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));

    // headers allow in request
    config.setAllowedHeaders(
            Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"));

    // headers exposed in response
    config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Token", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "Content-Disposition"));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

And also, I had to permitt all method of type Options, like that:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //csrf is disabled because we are not using cookies
    http.csrf().disable();

    // No session will be created or used by spring security
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    //Entry points
    http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/login").permitAll()
            //Disallow everything else
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()//<-- this one
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    //if a user try to access a resource without having enough permissions
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint);

    // Apply Header and JWT filters
    http.apply(new JwtTokenFilterConfigurer(headerVerificationFilter, jwtAuthorizationFilter, jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint));
}
```

Comment: that sounds right, modern browsers do no allow JS to access request headers without the server explicitly allowing it (via CORS). In turn, angular httpClient will not see the headers (because the browser is not forwarding them to JS)
So your CORS config around `config.setAllowedHeaders` must have set it.